# VBA outlook 2010 move

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

`m.display` works but `m.move(A)` does not.

The folder exist.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim A As Outlook.Folder
    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = 
           myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set A = myInbox.Folders("A")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim m As MailItem
    On Error Resume Next
    arr = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    Set m = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(arr(i))

    If m.SenderEmailAddress = "notifications@transcore.com" Then
        'MsgBox (m.Body)
        m.Display
        m.Move (A)
    End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a minor possible error you may encounter. `For i = 0 To UBound(arr)` should be `For i = 0 To UBound(arr) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Move is a function, not a sub. Move the message first, then display it:

```
set m = m.Move(A) 
m.Display
```