# Up to which version is the EntryIDCollection of the _NewMailEx event a comma-delimited string?

Tags: vba, outlook, documentation

I am working yet again with the `_NewMailEx` event of Outlook and am starting to get paranoid.

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) states:

> This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem , MeetingItem , or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Note that this behavior has changed from earlier versions of the event when the EntryIDCollection contained a list of comma-delimited Entry IDs of all the items received in the Inbox since the last time the event was fired. [...]

I am using Office 2010 at work and Office 2016 and 2019 at home and have never had any issues with expecting one event per mail.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171304(v%3Doffice.11)) Office 2003 document led me to believe that the change to the `_NewMailEx` event happened with Office 2007.
However [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42348518/8769365) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23154740) question explicitly state using Office 2010 and in both questions the OP `Split`s the string. There are also many other Outlook questions without an explicit version statement that `Split` the `EntryIDCollection`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45555331) question for example.

---

Am I wrong in my assumption?
**Up to which Office version is the `EntryIDCollection` of the `_NewMailEx` event a comma-delimited string?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you still continue using the old code by splitting the string passed as a parameter, it will be working correctly. After splitting the passed string you will get a single string (EntryID) anyway. Developers who created their solutions before these changes continue using the old way. So, don't be confused.

The changes for the `NewMailEx` event were rolled out (as patches or updates) to all MS Office versions supported. Office 2007 reached its end of support on October 10, 2017. The docs for Office 2010 clearly state that changes are applied to the `NewMailEx`, so you may expect it working starting from Outlook 2010.